# Replacing a HDD in FreeNAS

Tags: hard-drive, freebsd, truenas

I got a message that said one of my hard drive was degraded and im trying to figure out how to check which drive it is. I did zpool status and I got this

```
 zpool status
  pool: BiggyD
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  Sufficient replicas exist for
        the pool to continue functioning in a degraded state.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
   see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-2Q
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 1h20m with 0 errors on Fri May 29 01:20:40 2015
config:

        NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        BiggyD                                          DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
            gptid/16802538-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/171cea13-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/178aa7a7-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/17ee86d6-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/18a4d3c1-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad  ONLINE       0     0     0
            gptid/2b25eceb-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad  ONLINE       0     0     0
            9910768793305845771                         UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/gptid/2baa7b71-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad,
```

then when I put in

```
  [root@freenas] /tmp# glabel status
                                      Name  Status  Components
gptid/3154862c-cc57-11e4-8a32-f46d04005fad     N/A  da0p1
gptid/315e5391-cc57-11e4-8a32-f46d04005fad     N/A  da0p2
gptid/16802538-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada0p2
gptid/171cea13-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada1p2
gptid/716df18a-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada2p2
gptid/8c34eff6-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada3p2
gptid/533b27e1-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada4p2
gptid/178aa7a7-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada5p2
gptid/17ee86d6-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada6p2
gptid/18a4d3c1-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada7p2
gptid/2b25eceb-cc4a-11e4-b923-f46d04005fad     N/A  ada8p2
```

I cant find the hard drive matching the glabel status.
How do i find out which hard drive is bad? Thanks

Comment: How many drives are there physically in the machine?

Comment: Shouldn't this be available in the GUI?